# How to shorten array on get all user session data form table database?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, codeigniter, session

I have a problem to showing all user session data in PHP MySQL (Codeigniter).
For example, when I login by entering a username and password then the admin details page will show all my data.

Controller: Login.php

```
<?php
class Login extends CI_Controller{
    function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('datalogin');
    }

    function index(){

        $this->load->view('login');
    }

    function check(){
        $username=htmlspecialchars($this->input->post('username',TRUE),ENT_QUOTES);
        $password=htmlspecialchars($this->input->post('password',TRUE),ENT_QUOTES);

        $cek_user=$this->datalogin->auth_user($username,$password);

        if($cek_user->num_rows() > 0){
                $data=$cek_user->row_array();
                $this->session->set_userdata('good',TRUE);
                 if($data['level']=='10'){ //Administrator
                        $this->session->set_userdata('akses',$data['level']);
                        $this->session->set_userdata('session_id',$data['id']);
                        $this->session->set_userdata('session_name',$data['name']);
                        $this->session->set_userdata('session_username',$data['username']);
                        $namalevel = "Administrator";
                        $this->session->set_userdata('session_level',$level);
                        $this->session->set_userdata('session_foto',$data['foto']);
                        redirect('adminpage');
                     } if($data['level']=='1'){ //Leader
                        $this->session->set_userdata('akses',$data['level']);
                        $this->session->set_userdata('session_id',$data['id']);
                        $this->session->set_userdata('session_name',$data['name']);
                        $this->session->set_userdata('session_username',$data['username']);
                        $namalevel = "Leader";
                        $this->session->set_userdata('session_level',$level);
                        $this->session->set_userdata('session_foto',$data['foto']);
                    redirect('leaderpage');
                } else {
                    redirect('login/logout');
                }

        } else {
            $this->load->view('login');
        }
    }

    function logout(){
        $this->session->sess_destroy();
        redirect('login');
    }
}
```

This problem is writing very long arrays:

```
$this->session->set_userdata('akses',$data['level']);
$this->session->set_userdata('session_id',$data['id']);
$this->session->set_userdata('session_name',$data['name']);
$this->session->set_userdata('session_username',$data['username']);
$namalevel = "Administrator";
$this->session->set_userdata('session_level',$level);
$this->session->set_userdata('session_foto',$data['foto']);
//etc....................
```

is it possible to write down all the data if I have so much data of self?
is there another shorter way?

Model : Datalogin.php

```
class Datalogin extends CI_Model {

    function auth_user($username,$password){
        $query=$this->db->query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE username='$username' AND password=md5('$password') LIMIT 1");
        return $query;
    }

    function data_user(){
        return $query=$this->db->query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE id='" .$_SESSION['id']."'");   
    }
}
```

if I filter based on a user who logged in, add this script in the controller is also not running.

```
$access = $this->datalogin->data_user()->row_array(); 
$login = $this->session->set_userdata($access);
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking for, so I'll only comment: I don't think it's best idea to store everything in session. Better - store id of the logged in user, and then you can query for it from the DB.

Answer (score 0):

I really don't see how you can "shorten" or otherwise minimize that information. You could offload some things so that you just save, for example, the userid and user level, and then use the userid to get the rest of the information when you need it. But I don't see a problem with storing only 5 strings/ints in session vars if you use them a lot.

You can make the code a little nicer by doing something like this:

```
$array = array(
    'akses' => $data['level'],
    'session_id' => $data['id'],
    'session_name' => $data['name'],
    'session_username' => $data['username'],
    'session_level' => 'Administrator',
    'session_foto' => $data['foto']
);

$this->session->set_userdata($array);
```

But it will not change the functionality.

As for your second question (please in the future stick to 1 question per post) I see 3 potential issues:

```
function data_user(){
    return $query=$this->db->query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE id='" .$_SESSION['id']."'");   
}
```

I never see `$_SESSION['id']` being set; did you mean `session_id` here?

Also just return the object without assigning it to a var:

```
    return $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE id='" .$_SESSION['session_id']."'");
```

Further, I wouldn't store the whole `array()` like you do `$this->datalogin->data_user()->row_array();` Just get it when you need it.